# Is there a way to apply uv texture in the middle of animaton?

Tags: texturing, uv

I want to apply a UV texture (on the selected object)  in this frame but when I enter edit mode it pops back to the original position, can anyone tell me how to apply UV texture in the frame and this position? thanks

[image]

Comment: what kind of animation have you going? What Modifiers are active?

Comment: I was making some flowing paper and and I want to make them stick to the wall (as the image) and form an image. But when I try to put on uv texture and turn on edit mode, it just back to the original position and The paper are using cloth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To unwrap it in the cloth simulated position you need to apply the cloth sim as shapekey, then activate that shapekey and project your texture in editmode, then delete the shapekey and add the clothsim back in.

Comment: It works, Thank you so much